# I am using Vim 7.4. I do not have admin privilege to update it. I want to use plugins as I cannot use plugin manager

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I download Vim-plug but I am unable to use it.

I have downloaded NERDTree in `~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree`.

But when I give command `:NERDTree` in gVim editor it gives an error:

```
Not an editor command : NERDTree
```

Comment: What is your OS (Linux, Windows)?

Comment: I've been compiling vim in my $HOME for more than to decades now. I've never needed admin privileges to do so.

Answer (score 1):

7th version does not support `:h packages`.

Therefore, you have to update your `:h 'runtimepath'` manually. Or simply merge the plugin files/dirs into your ".vim" directory subtree (which is kind of a mess, yeah).

Comment: With the pathogen plugin you can  avoid the mess. I think it also backports the package feature

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Basically, pathogen manages runtimepath. For anything, except of a whole pile of other plugins, one could do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt suggested add to your `.vimrc` the following line:

```
set runtimepath^=~/vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree
```

Comment: No "pack" in 7.4.

Comment: @Romain is always right :-) You need Vim 8 for my solution.

Comment: If you have Vim 7.4 like @Romain said you have to select the solution of @Matt. Basically merge the NerdTree folder structure with your `.vim` folder structure (it is a mess) or play with the `runtimepath`